# What's the difference between these two statements

Tags: c++, oop

What's the difference between these two statements?

```
ob.A::ar[0] = 200;
ob.ar[0] = 200;
```

where `ob` is an object of class `A`

```
class A
{
    public:
        int *ar;
        A()
        {
            ar = new int[100];
        }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case there is no difference.

This notation:

`obj.Class::member`

is only to solve the ambiguities coming from inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
  int a;
}

class B {
public:
  int a;
}

class C : public A, B {
   void func() {
      // this objects holds 2 instance variables of name "a" inherited from A and B
      this->A::a = 1;
      this->B::a = 2;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference. The explicit namespace qualification of `ar` is redundant in this case.

It might not be redundant in cases where (multiple, nonvirtual) inheritance redefines the name `ar`. Sample (contrived):

```
#include <string>

class A 
{
    public:
        int *ar;
        A() { ar = new int[100]; }
        // unrelated, but prevent leaks: (Rule Of Three)
       ~A() { delete[] ar; }
    private:
        A(A const&);
        A& operator=(A const&);
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        std::string ar[12];
};


int main()
{
    B ob;
    ob.A::ar[0] = 200;
    ob.ar[0] = "hello world";
}
```

See it on http://liveworkspace.org/code/d25889333ec378e1382cb5af5ad7c203

Comment: can you explain what you've written as private code in class A ?

Comment: @Rushil Well, that is really off-topic: it's the quickest way to prevent `A` from being copied (which would lead to double deletion of `A::ar`). It's called [Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) or, in C++11 [Rule Of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) instead :)

Comment: Okay. I know that's off topic but I wanted to know what that meant. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is no difference. However imagine that ob is of class C that inherits both from class A and class B and both A and B have a field ar. Then there will be no other way to access ar but to explicitly specify which of the inherited data members you are refering to.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to read this

```
ob.A::ar[0] = 200;
ob.ar[0] = 200;
```

like this

`A::ar[0]` it's the same thing for `ar[0]`, so the 2 rows are basically the same thing and the operator `::` is used to indicate the so called *resolution of the namespace*, or just the namespace.

since `ob` is an object of type A, the namespace resolution is implicit and you do not need `A::` before accessing `ar[0]`.